# Directional derivative conflicts with normal derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am learning about directional derivative and the definition bothered me so much.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}} = \vec{\nabla}f . \vec{v}$

which by extension can be written as

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}} = (\vec{\nabla}f . \hat{v})||\vec{v}||$

So that would mean derivative of $f$ along $\vec{2x}$ will be

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{2x}} = (\vec{\nabla}f . \hat{i})2 = 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial(2x)}$ should be $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Why there is a difference?

Note: I am beginner to multivariate calculus, so the question is probably a silly misunderstanding of the concepts. I will be glad if you can clarify it. Thank you.

Comment: Rather think of it like $d/dx f(y(x))$ where $y(x)=2x$.

Comment: Or even better, as $d/dt f(x(t), y(t))$ where $(x(t),y(t))=d*t$ and $d=(2,0)$ is the direction (in your case).

Comment: Your confusion is a good reason that this notation for directional derivative is horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you should think about the directional derivative is this: Take any parametrized curve through $p$ with velocity vector $\vec v$ at $p$. Compute the rate of change of $f$ along this curve at the instant you pass through $p$. (Then it's clear that if you're moving twice as fast, the function is changing twice as fast at that instant.)

**COMMENT**: Personally, I prefer the notation $D_{\vec v}f(p)$ for the directional derivative.

Comment: I guess I understood now. $\partial f/ \partial 2x$ is basically $lim_{h \to 0} (f(\vec{x}+ (h/2)\hat{i}) - f(\vec{x}) ) / h$ so it evaluates into $(1/2)\partial f/ \partial x$ But as $\nabla_{\vec{v}}f(x)$ is $lim_{h \to 0} (f(\vec{x}+2h\hat{i}) - f(\vec{x}) ) / h$ it becomes $2\partial f/ \partial x$ .

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash Personally, I would never write $df/d(2x)$.